# Dynamically check if stripe account is active php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am currently using Stripe for a payment processor on a site and also have a backup payment processor with another company. As directed by Stripe I include the js.stripe.com script on each page of the site to protect against fraud. I am also using the php sdk for the backend processing of payments combined with the elements.js script for grabbing and sending the card data to the backend processing.

Can anyone help me with how I would setup a check to verify the stripe account is active and accepting payments with php so my system will know to load Stripe if it is active and/or fallback to my backup payment processor if for some reason the Stripe account is suspended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the "retrieve account" endpoint in the Stripe API with no arguments, it'll return information on the account the secret API key is associated with: https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve?lang=php

From there you can check to see if [`charges_enabled`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object?lang=php#account_object-charges_enabled) is set to `true`, if not then the account is probably disabled.